# Using global variables in a function in Julia

Tags: julia

how do I create/use a global variable inside of a function?

If I make the Global variable in one function, how do I reference it in a subsequent function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you would need to do:

```
function a()
    global z = 0
    print(z)
end

function b()
    global z += 1
    print(z)
end
```

Note that in Function `b`, if you do not reference `z` as `global z`, it will look in the local scope of the function where there is no `z` variable defined and give an error:

```
julia> b()
ERROR: UndefVarError: z not defined

julia> a() # defines z in global scope
0

julia> b() # works now because z has been defined
1
```

Edit: *As Michael pointed out in the comment below, it is not generally a good idea to use this sort of global paradigm in practice. This can result in code that is difficult to debug, understand, and potentially invalid outputs.*

Comment: You might add that capturing variables, in particular non-const globals, is a very poor idea in most cases https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-global-variables-1 and https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-captured-1